# Replacing all words that are part of variable names

Tags: r, string, replace

I am writing R code in Visual Studio Code and would like to replace all words in strings that have the following format:

```
c("c22lineoftext", "h12another_line_of_text")
```

to:

```
c("c22var", "h12var")
```

I am having some trouble figuring out the correct regex to handle these cases.

What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as @Park with base R:

```
paste0(sub("(\\w\\d{2}).*", "\\1", x), "var")
```

```
[1] "c22var" "h12var"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about pattern, but you may try

```
library(stringr)

x <- c("c22lineoftext", "h12another_line_of_text")

paste0(str_extract(x, "\\w\\d{2}"), "var")

[1] "c22var" "h12var"
```